# How to detect gsm modem using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am a newbee in vb.net. Want to know how to get port of a connected gsm modem programmatically using vb.net

Dim MgmtSearch As ManagementObjectSearcher

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In MgmtSearch.Get()
        If queryObj("Status") = "OK" Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(queryObj("Description"))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MgmtSearch = New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem ")
End Sub
```

The above code I am using but getting An `unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Serial Port Project.exe` error when clicking button.

I am using Dlink Modem and vb.net 2015

Comment: Read this article for help on debugging null reference exceptions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Comment: i know what the error means,but need to know the cause of such errors...

Comment: Then read the section on debugging. If you need more help then let us know which line the exception occurs on.

Comment: For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In MgmtSearch.Get() ---line generates the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is failing on my machine with an "Invalid Parameters" exception:

```
MgmtSearch = New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem ")
```

This is due to the double slash replace it with `"root\CIMV2"` instead and it will start working.

I'm not sure how the form continued to load after this exception occurred but the result is that `MgmtSearch` is `null`.

Comment: Here's some info on why it's not catching that exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a/4934010#4934010